# Apply the average to a timedelta column for two group conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in Python:

| ID | country_ID | visit_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ESP | 10 days 12:03:00 |
| 0 | ENG | 5 days 10:02:00 |
| 1 | ENG | 3 days 08:05:03 |
| 1 | ESP | 1 days 03:02:00 |
| 1 | ENG | 2 days 07:01:03 |
| 1 | ENG | 3 days 01:00:52 |
| 2 | ENG | 0 days 12:01:02 |
| 2 | ENG | 1 days 22:10:03 |
| 2 | ENG | 0 days 20:00:50 |

For each ID, I want to get:

**avg_visit_ESP and avg_visit_ENG columns.**

- Average time visit with country_ID = ESP for each ID.
- Average time visit with country_ID = ENG for each ID.

| ID | avg_visit_ESP | avg_visit_ENG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 days 12:03:00 | 5 days 10:02:00 |
| 1 | 1 days 03:02:00 | (8 days 16:06:58) / 3 |
| 2 | NaT | (3 days 06:11:55) / 3 |

I don't know how to specify in groupby a double grouping, first by ID and then by country_ID. If you can help me I would appreciate it.

P.S.: The date format of visit_time (timedelta), can perform addition and division without any apparent problem.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    date1 = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-04 10:10:21', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    date2 = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-05 20:15:41', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    date3 = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-07 20:15:41', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    sum1date = date2-date1
    sum2date = date3-date2
    sum3date = date3-date1
    print((sum1date+sum2date+sum3date)/3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(df.groupby(['ID', 'country_ID'])['visit_time']
   .mean(numeric_only=False)
   .unstack()
   .add_prefix('avg_visit_')
)
```

should do the trick

```
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')
>>> df.columns = [s.strip() for s in df]
>>> df['visit_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['visit_time'])
>>> df.groupby(['ID', 'country_ID'])['visit_time'].mean(numeric_only=False).unstack().add_prefix('avg_visit_') 
country_ID            avg_visit_ENG    avg_visit_ESP 
ID                                                   
0                    5 days 10:02:00 10 days 12:03:00
1          2 days 21:22:19.333333333  1 days 03:02:00
2          1 days 02:03:58.333333333              NaT
```